# RefProp in Mathematica

Tags: interoperability, chemistry, external-calls

`RefProp` by NIST is a program that calculates the thermodynamic properties of fluids. I need to call certain `RefProp` functions from inside *Mathematica*.

Can any one here, who has experience calling `RefProp` functions from *Mathematica*, tell me how to do this??

Answer (score 4):

Mathematica's [`ThermodynamicData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ThermodynamicData) function uses refprop under the hood, so you can do stuff like:

```
ThermodynamicData[
    "R32",
    "Enthalpy",
    {"Temperature"->Quantity[32, "DegreesCelsius"], "Pressure"->Quantity[10000,"Pascals"]}
]
```

> Quantity[567942., ("Joules")/("Kilograms")]

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem but I was told [here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20131215203548AAFrspd) that it was impossible.

So, looking for other alternatives I've found it! 
It's called *CoolProp*.

Given the source files and a *Mathematica* link file, you need to build a *Mathematica*-compatible `CoolProp.dll` yourself. Get them from [GitHub](https://github.com/ibell/coolprop/tree/master/wrappers/Mathematica)

Now, I can use it with ease.

Comment: Doesn't RefProp package come already with .dll file? I am working with another dll thermodynamic properties tables and I guess that if You know the structure of functions in Your dll file You can implement them in _Mathematica_ simply using `DefineDLLFunction`.

Comment: You also need to first load .NET/Link using `Needs["NETLink`"]` to use dll files in _Mathematica_.